# css parameter for text that will ignore whole website formating

Tags: html, css, text

http://www.pawelbaranski.com/ - this is my website.

I want my webpage title to be in left corner, in the same line menu is.

I don't know much about html/css, but the easiest way to do it that i figured out, is to add my page title to header, because wordpress provides tool to do that easly.

Of course, when i add some text to header, then every other element of the websites will move down, and the title will be above the website. I don't want that to happen.

So i figured out, there must be some parameter that will tell my title to ignore rest of my website, and leave it's position unaffected.

Does such parameter exist? how to use it?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is add it to your header and add the css `display:inlinie-block` this will stop it pushing the menu down.

However you may need to add some media queries to better cope with mobile screens etc.

```html
<h1 style="display:inline-block;">
  <a class="h1" href="/">
    <strong>PAWEŁ BARAŃSKI</strong> FOTOGRAFIA
  </a>
</h1>
```

It does work:
[image]

Comment: I copied&pasted your code but it didn't work. Whole website moved down after adding text with inline-block property.

Comment: Where are you pasting it? Seems you are not pasting it in the correct place, I'm happy to tell you the right place but since im the only one helping you and you down vote me you can figure it out by yourself.

Comment: I didn't downvoted you. I also have been downvoted. Somebody just didn't like my question :P

Comment: can you inspect on browser and take a screenshot of where that code is ending up on your page?

Comment: Ok so it would seem this is a case of poor wording by the theme designer. It looks like the box you are putting that code in is for HEAD scripts NOT HEADER. You need to edit the actual php code to change that unless there is another setting for it in the theme.

Comment: Okay, i tried editing actual php code. I tried editing content-header.php, and then top-section.php. this is the result - https://imgur.com/a/uUxnS3I

the title got below the menu now.... and no polish letters are displayed.